# Navbar embaixo de jumbotron?

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou criando um layout e estou tentando colocar um `navbar` embaixo de um `jumbotron` mas nao estou conseguindo. Acontece que o `jumbotron` fica com um espaço no topo e o `navbar` fica com um espaço entre o `jumbotron`.

Como resolver isso ?

```
<!-- Header.cshtml to use as a Partial to include on main layout -->

<div class="jumbotron bg-red">
    <h1>My first layout</h1>
    <h3>Trying to create a layout using jumbotron and navbar</h3>
</div><!--jumbotron-->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="navbar-brand"><img src="~/Imagens/logo.png" width="32" height="32" title="Red Cherry" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--nav bar-->
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

para resolver isso ai você tera que mexer no CSS do bootstrap, lá a propriedade que você esta usando se não me engano tem 48px de padding, é so remover que resolve o problema... portanto certa vez mesmo eu retirando não sei porque mais no servidor locar ainda estava com espaço, mais quando mandei pro servidor web foi estava com as alterações empregadas!